# Automatically adding the character * (asterisk) at the input box without doing anything

Tags: addtocart, checkout-page

I'm working on the compatibility of our client site. Upon checking, I have noted that in the checkout, on the field **Postnummer** it is automatically adding the character * in the field without doing anything. Below is the screenshot for your reference.

[image]

I have inspected the input box and below is the screenshot:

[image]

The above-said issue appears only in mobile devices.

**Update:**

I have checked the admin panel and see that we have put * to **Default Post Code** in **Stores**->**Configuration**->**Sales**->**Tax**->**Default Tax Destination Calculation**

[image]

I think this is the reason why the * is displaying in the Postcode input field at the front-end. Now my question is, can I remove this * from the admin panel. Will it cause any issues because of removing *?

Could anyone please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Is anybody got this problem?

Comment: You are right with your idea that this system setting causes your "issue" just remove it it will not have any sideeffects

Comment: @PhilippSander Thanks. Let me try it. Do you have any idea why this issue occurs only in mobile devices?

Comment: this depends on your theme